# When is MEF shipping?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, mef, extensibility

I'm building a product that will ship after .Net 4.0 is released.

Is MEF an integral part of .Net 4.0, so I can count on them being released together, or is it some external component that might be released separately and thus it is dangerous to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MEF is the part of .NET Framework 4.0. It is located in assembly System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll. You can learn more here: [MEF in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[The Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) (MEF) **is a new library in .NET Framework 4.0** that addresses this problem by simplifying the design of extensible applications and components.